# How to search for specific mail (by msgid) in Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird

Recently, our mail system had a serious failure and some mails were lost. However, our admin gave us the sender's address together with a `Message-Id` to contact him for retransmission. So I got also some of these requests. When entering the msgid in Thunderbirds search field I am not able to find it. Using `grep` inside of the .thunderbird folder, gave me multiple hits, so I could figure out which mail account was in action and I finally found the mail by manually inspecting all headers of the very recent mails sent from that account. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Thunderbird-native way of doing this is answered on https://superuser.com/a/461509/283161.

Additionally, there is a Thunderbird extension called [MessageID-Finder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/messageid-finder/).

Comment: MessageID-Finder is marked as uncompatible with newer stable TB versions. But thank you very much for the native way..